# Lagrange's identity: Why is the sum such that it is?

Tags: vector-analysis

Lagrange's identity is:

$$
\sum_{1\leq j <k\leq n}(a_jb_k-a_kb_j)^2=\left( \sum_{k=1}^na_k^2 \right)\left( \sum_{k=1}^n b_k^2 \right)-\left( \sum_{k=1}^na_kb_k \right)^2
$$

Why is the LHS sum such that it is? If one considers a $n\times n $ matrix, and the elements (j, k) in it, then reading the sum in the matrix shows that one picks values from the upper half above the diagonal.

Is there some insight to be gained from the matrix to understand why the Lagrange identity is such that it is?

Comment: what would you prefer?

Comment: @WillJagy The problem is that having this sum form hides the fact, that the Lagrange's identity is probably derived from the cross product (in three dimensional Euclidean space). But as it's in a sum form, then one initially thinks that this is something different, more general.

Comment: Or is this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_identity#Proof_of_algebraic_form what one should be looking at? I'm introduced to this in a vector analysis class.

Comment: Mostly, I think you should carefully prove it for $n=1,2,3,$ which should not be too bad, and go from there. Or disprove it, that would be interesting

Comment: @WillJagy So this is a result in algebra and not specific to vector spaces?

Comment: I have no opinion. I think you would learn something if you proved it yourself for small $n.$

Comment: Yeah so after doing n = 1,2,3 it does seem to be more algebraic. Reminds of binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, Lagranges Identity can be interpreted geometrically as follows. I am not aware of your background so I will skip a proof which shows the following but you can expand the following expression given vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ with $n$ components, the LHS of the identity is exactly:

$$(\vec a \times \vec b)\bullet(\vec a \times \vec b)$$

The funny-ness of it is also apparent when using some tricks in tensor algebra if you are interested. Pavel Grinfield's book on tensor calculus of moving surfaces is a great book to learn more about it.

Comment: Solid answer!  Well done.  +1